# Неправильно записывается файл С++ fwrite()

Tags: c++, файлы

Пытаюсь прочитать exe и записать в другой файл, но после записи он не выполняется

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    FILE * firstFile;
    FILE * secondFile;
    BYTE * buffer;

    firstFile = fopen("calc.exe", "rb");
    if (firstFile == NULL) return 1;
    secondFile = fopen("sss.exe", "wb");
    if (secondFile == NULL) return 1;

    fseek(firstFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    unsigned long s2 = ftell(firstFile);

    buffer = (BYTE *)malloc(s2);

    int read = fread(buffer, 1, s2, firstFile);
    perror("fread");
    int write = fwrite(buffer, 1, s2, secondFile);
    perror("fwrite");

    free(buffer);

    fclose(firstFile);
    fclose(secondFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Не работает не только с exe, но и с любыми другими файлами.
Кто-то знает как решить эту проблему?

Comment: *"не работает"* не является описанием проблемы

Comment: Указатель в файле на конец передвинули, обратно не вернули. Результат `fread` не проверили. Он ничего не прочитал, в буфере остался мусор. Мусор записан во второй файл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fseek(firstFile, 0, SEEK_END);
unsigned long s2 = ftell(firstFile);
```

А назад, на начало файла кто будет указатель откатывать? Дейкстра? :)

```
fseek(firstFile, 0, SEEK_END);
unsigned long s2 = ftell(firstFile);
fseek(firstFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: Ну и? Анонимный минусатор, в чем я неправ? Если о том, что `buffer` не освобождается, то это не относится к делу, а в данной программе, которая тут же завершает выполнение — просто вполне допустимо :)

Comment: думаю, что придет Дейкстра и скажет, что ответ "недружелюбный"

Comment: @KoVadim В таком случае, у нас с ним разные понятия о дружелюбии :)

Comment: ну как по мне, то ответ немного грубоватенький. Как сейчас модно говорить "токсичненький". и любой молодой программист (рожденный после 2000) (ой, а это уже эйджизм), может получить травму, не совместимую с программированием.

Comment: @KoVadim Если программист в состоянии от этого получить травму — он занялся в жизни не тем. Тут надо быть очень стрессоустойчивым. Кстати, а их не травмирует, что им вообще на ошибки указывают? Может, это делать нельзя, надо говорить — у вас замечательный код, который улучшить нельзя, поэтому я его немного ухудшу, чтоб он заработал? :)

Comment: добро пожаловать в новый дивный мир:)